# How to use call an item from a library based on props in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I would like to allow a user to choose their Icon from AntD Icons to display on my component.

Here are the docs for AntD Icons

https://ant.design/components/icon/

I import the icons (to have access to all of them) via `import * as Icons from "@ant-design/icons";`

For example if someone passes in a prop of `icon="DownOutlined"` I want to display the Icon from AntD. In order to display that icon I could hardcode `<Icons.DownOutlined />`, but how I do I change what comes after the `.` based on the props?

I have tried:

```
import * as Icons from "@ant-design/icons";

const Comp = (props) => {

  const { 
         icon: "DownloadOutlined"
         label: "Hello World" 
         } = props;

return <p>{label}<Icons.`${icon}` /></p>

}
```

and I have also tried `<Icons[icon] />` neither of which work.

Comment: can you console log Icons[icon] and share the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import * as Icons from "@ant-design/icons";

const Comp = (props) => {
  const { icon: "DownloadOutlined", label: "Hello World" } = props;
  const DownloadOutlinedIcon = Icons[icon];
  
  return <p>{label}<DownloadOutlinedIcon/></p>
}
```